# Using regex to split pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to using pattern in regular expression. I have read a couple of links from Microsoft site, thought I understood but I came across this scenario and do not know why it is not providing the results I expected.

I would like to split MyCmd into a list of strings: print,a,+,b,;
Normal split will not keep the delimiters as far as I understand. So, I think I have tried using regex with the pattern defined below: 
(basically I want to split the string into a list or queue and keep the delimiters ;,+-*/{}[]).

```
 string MyCmd = "print a+b;";
 private string MyDelim = @"\b[\s;,\+\-\*\/%=\<\>\(\)\{\}\[\]]\w+";
 myStuff = new Queue<string>(Regex.Split(MyCmd,MyDelim));
```

But so far, my code above is not yielding the expected results.

What is not correct in my pattern?

Comment: Do you get `print`, empty string, and `;`? And what do you expect to get?

Comment: Yes, that is what I get. But I would like to get print,a,+,b,;

Comment: Maybe `var MyDelim = @"([][\s;,+*/%=<>(){}-])";
            var myStuff = Regex.Split(MyCmd,MyDelim).Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList();` will do? I get `print`, `a`, `+`, `b`, `;` as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use

```
var MyCmd = "print a+b;";
var MyDelim = @"([][\s;,+*/%=<>(){}-])";
var myStuff = Regex.Split(MyCmd,MyDelim).Where(p=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)).ToList();
```

Output: `print`, `a`, `+`, `b`, `;`

[image]

Note that the `([][\s;,+*/%=<>(){}-])` regex is enclosed with `(...)` and that *capturing group* makes sure the captured values also get added to the resulting array.

You need the `.Where(p=> !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))` to get rid of empty values that you will get with `Regex.Split`.

I removed excessive escaping in your regex so that it looks "lean and mean".

The reason your regex does not work is that `@"\b[\s;,\+\-\*\/%=\<\>\(\)\{\}\[\]]\w+"` matches the spaces and symbols in the character class after a `\b` word boundary (requiring a word character to appear before them) and then it matched one or more word characters. Since there is no capturing group, all the matches disappeared from the resulting array.

Comment: It works! Just curious, I thought special character like {}[]() have to be escaped? Not true?

Comment: Almost all special characters inside a character class `[...]` lose their special meaning, except for `^`, `-`, and `]`. The `^` if placed first, negates the character class (match all chars other than those inside). The `]` inside a character class does not have to be escaped when placed first. `-` does not have to be escaped if placed at the start/end or after a range, or after a shorthand character class. (Note that `^` that is not right after the opening `[` matches a literal `^` symbol.)

Comment: @splash: That comment above is wrong, `IgnorePatternWhitespace` does not discard the whitespace/empty values from the resulting array. It is only used to ignore whitespace in some parts of the pattern to make it more readable and use inline comments without having to use the `(?#...)` syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I see. No wonder you have placed ] before [. The sequence order matters! Tricky!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You are right! RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace does not actually discard the space, empty string. So what is the option for?

Comment: In the current pattern of mine, this `IgnorePatternWhitespace` is not necessary, since it does not ignore spaces inside a character class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`Regex.Split` is the way to go. If using `Regex.Matches`, you can do like this:

```
string MyCmd = @"print  a+b;";
string MyDelim = @"([^;,+\-*/{}\[\]\)\(\s]+|[;,+\-*/{}\[\]\)\(])";
var myStuff = Regex.Matches(MyCmd, MyDelim).Cast<Match>().ToList().ConvertAll(m => m.Groups[1].Value.ToString());
```